# Sending email without user intervention in android

Tags: android, email

Without using the default mail application and with a click of a single button i would like to send the mail from my app.

i followed this link :

[Sending Email in Android using JavaMail API without using the default/built-in app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2020088/sending-email-in-android-using-javamail-api-without-using-the-default-android-app/2033124#2033124)

added permission to the mainfest file, still its not working.
kindly help.

The app force closes when i open it on my device.

My logcat file reads:

```
08-23 15:10:26.126: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(18094): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
08-23 15:10:26.126: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(18094): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{org.mailsend/org.mailsend.MailSenderActivity.java}: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.mailsend.MailSenderActivity.java in loader dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[/mnt/asec/org.mailsend-2/pkg.apk]
08-23 15:10:26.126: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(18094):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1743)
08-23 15:10:26.126: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(18094):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1851)
08-23 15:10:26.126: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(18094):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:132)
08-23 15:10:26.126: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(18094):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1038)
08-23 15:10:26.126: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(18094):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
08-23 15:10:26.126: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(18094):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:143)
08-23 15:10:26.126: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(18094):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4277)
08-23 15:10:26.126: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(18094):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
08-23 15:10:26.126: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(18094):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
08-23 15:10:26.126: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(18094):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
08-23 15:10:26.126: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(18094):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
08-23 15:10:26.126: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(18094):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
08-23 15:10:26.126: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(18094): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.mailsend.MailSenderActivity.java in loader dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[/mnt/asec/org.mailsend-2/pkg.apk]
08-23 15:10:26.126: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(18094):     at dalvik.system.PathClassLoader.findClass(PathClassLoader.java:240)
08-23 15:10:26.126: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(18094):     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:551)
08-23 15:10:26.126: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(18094):     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:511)
08-23 15:10:26.126: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(18094):     at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1061)
08-23 15:10:26.126: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(18094):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1735)
08-23 15:10:26.126: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(18094):     ... 11 more
```

The code I used is same as the one in
[Sending Email in Android using JavaMail API without using the default/built-in app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2020088/sending-email-in-android-using-javamail-api-without-using-the-default-android-app)

This is my mainfest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  package="org.mailsend"
  android:versionCode="1"
  android:versionName="1.0"
  android:installLocation="preferExternal" >
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"></uses-permission>


<application android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="@string/app_name"       android:debuggable="true">
    <activity android:name=".MailSenderActivity.java"
              android:label="@string/app_name">
              <activity android:name=".GMailSender"></activity>
               <activity android:name=".MailSenderActivity"></activity>
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>

    </activity>


</application>
```

Comment: Can android do **that**?  Could it send as you, or just decide to send random stuff from your memory card back to home base? Sounds vaguely scary.

Comment: Please be more specific, post the logcat of your errors, post the code that's not working. Help people help you

Comment: @user838522 what is the Error in your LogCat?

Comment: sorry since my rep is less on SO, I'm unable to paste images, so I've pasted the logcat as it is.

Comment: @Paul: Of course Android can do that. Give it internet permissions and SD card permissions and it'll be able to open a connection to a webserver (any type including file or mail), and systematically upload your entire sd card. Though it'll need to be run at least once allowing it to start a service so that it wont be shut down by Android...

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the `org.mailsend.MailSenderActivity` class in your APK file, so it cannot be started. Either add this class to your APK file or modify the manifest to not include it (and do not try to start it).

Comment: that doesn't seem to be the problem and org.mailsend.MailSenderActivity is present in the class file.

Comment: @user838522: It is the problem that is reported by your stack trace.

Comment: I have one package called org.mailsend which holds 2 classes called GmailSender.java and MailSenderActivity.java and another package called com.provider which holds JSSEProvider.java; but why wouldn't it automatically add the packages into my apk file?

Comment: @user838522: I have no means of answering that question, sorry.

Answer (score 0):

1. Check the package name in GMailSender.java file

   ```
     static {   
             Security.addProvider(new PACKED-NAME.JSSEProvider());   
            }
   ```
2. add code in JSSEProvider file

   ```
   public final class JSSEProvider extends Provider {

       private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;   ---> this code is add
   ```